# Disable custom index on CMS. Will CD indexing be affected?

Tags: lucene, indexing, sitecore

I setup a custom Lucene index for several template types in Sitecore in a 1 CA and 3 CD environment. This works fine on the CD servers but this seems to be overloading the CMS server. If I comment out this index on CMS will it in anyway affect the indexing on CD servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't affect the CD servers unless you have some kind of file or configuration replication between the two that may move the index files or the sitecore config.

On a side note : The lucene indexing part should have very little impact on any server its running on (unless you maybe have custom indexers) so I'm a little confused while it would overload the CMS server.

Comment: I am using the AdvancedDatabaseCrawler implementation that Alex Shyba suggested.

Indexing was one of the things I noticed that was constantly happening so I want to rule out any problems with it. The index only has non-essential templates configured in it now so there isn't any heavy indexing going on at this point.